# Premiers mots d'un président ?

Tags: expressions

Après cinq minutes d’applaudissement pour le nouveau président, ces premières manifestations de la célébration de son arrivée au pouvoir ont fini et le président Macron a interjeté un premier mot :

> « Allez ... »

Quand j’attendais du flair, j'ai ressenti de la monotonie. Cela m'a étonné qu'il n'ait pas dit

> « Avec votre aide nous avons gagné »

ou

> « Merci »

Quels mots et phrases sont aptes à rompre un applaudissement de félicitation, comme pour le président élu ? C'est la transcription de la première adresse du président, qui commence par « Allez. »

Answer (score 4):

Cohérent,

— quand le domaine de son tout nouveau mouvement politique en 2016 est « *en-marche*.fr »,

— quand l’hymne national débute par « *Allons* enfants de la patrie … ».

Comment: Il serait intéressant de savoir quel contexte particulier de l'utilisation de cette interjection/injonction vous avez en vue comme base de l'explication du sens véritable de ce mot dans la bouche du président ; il existe de nombreuses significations ; faut-il entendre qu'il en a créé une nouvelle ? De laquelle s'agit-il ? Ça m'échappe complètement.

Comment: Le président Macron a créé un mouvement ex-nihilo, le vote confirme la réussite de son action. Ce n’est surtout pas parce que la campagne est terminée qu’il faut tout arrêter alors que changer les habitudes a été le symbole fort de son engagement. Il peut maintenant mettre en route ses réformes. Ce n’est pas "On a gagné le match" mais "le feu est vert, en route" et donc : Allez [vous qui avez choisi cette évolution du paysage politique] ne vous endormez pas sur vos lauriers, il y a beaucoup à faire, d’autres victoires sont à remporter,  il n’y a plus de temps à perdre…

Comment: Je comprends, mais c'est assez bizarre puisque le contexte correspondrait plutôt à ce que j'entrevois comme négatif dans ma réponse si ce n'était pas pour cette magique du mot « allez », que malheureusement je n'aurais pas moi-même identifiée ; quand même, on ne peut pas vraiment dire qu'il coupe court aux effusions de joie puisqu'il attend patiemment pendant cinq minutes  que les applaudissement se soient tus.

Comment: @LPH — Les vibrations de l’ambiance et le plaisir de savourer un moment d’intense émotions ne s’accordent pas avec votre interprétation : il ne coupe pas court aux effusions de joie, mais les recueille comme un artiste à là fin du spectacle, elles lui donnent une énergie qui … le remet *en-marche*

Answer (score 1):

Les possibilités suggérées sont assez traditionnelles mais je ne pourrais pas  prendre le recours à leur usage par la personne fêtée comme une indication particulière de son flair ni non plus d'une monotonie dans son approche ; que l'on ait eu à ce moment-là une certaine soif pour l'inédit, pour l'originalité — quand n'en avons-nous pas une dans ces instants peu communs ? — se comprend mais on ne peut pas oublier que de satisfaire cette soif n'est pas un devoir de l'orateur ; en d'autres mots on ne peut pas escompter et exiger de l'originalité en tout et toujours. C'est cependant ce dont le président a fait preuve à mon avis, d'originalité, mais à un tel niveau de banalité, celui de la plus populaire des interjections dont on puisse se servir couramment en français, qu'on aurait tout d'un coup pu se sentir dans le premier café venu en train d'écouter les propos d'un consommateur à l'élocution informelle ou même vulgaire.

Il n'y a pas, selon mon point de vue, une catégorie d'approches bien déterminées dans le but d'enchainer sur la liesse dont on est soudainement l'objet lorsque dans la position d'un président qui vient d'être élu, sauf qu'elles pourraient tendre vers des réactions empathiques, des réactions exprimant un enthousiasme partagé. Tout ce qui peut être préconisé c'est ce que ces réactions ne devraient pas être : monotones, à contre courant, données à l'abnégation, … ; ce n'est pas le moment propice pour faire part au monde que de se réjouir est une chose mais que d'attendre des résultats en est une autre. Il serait très original par exemple de reconnaitre l'enthousiasme de la foule et en coupant court à cela avec un mais à l'effet que l'on pense à passer au travail et qu'il y aura tout le temps de se réjouir plus tard ; cela, par exemple, serait de l'inédit, mais un tel refroidissement de l'élan de l'audience que l'on ne le fera jamais.
Il existe un type de réaction bien comprise des politiciens qui consiste à faire des déclarations d'espoir dans la réussite commune sur la nouvelle voie que vient d'ouvrir l'évènement ; ce type de réaction n'est pas ce que l'on peut appeler très original, mais d'un autre côté on doit considérer que si ça représente une réalité, c'est une réalité loin d'être négligeable, qu'il est très légitime de souligner par une déclaration. Non, je ne penche pas pour une forme stéréotypée de réaction de la part des élus dont on fête le succès, et ne crois pas que l'on puisse penser qu'elle serait nécessaire, même si c'est une façon de penser qui laisse la porte ouverte aux « allez » d'un monsieur macron.

Answer (score 0):

Pour interrompre une salve d'applaudissements, rien de tel qu'une surprise générale (par exemple en hurlant des propos incompréhensibles en allemand).

Mais si le Président doit parler et se faire comprendre, je suggère l'endormissement général, grâce à un discours long et monotone, marqué de pauses incongrues et de grandes hésitations, souvent de reprises, parfois de digressions ne presentant ni logique ni intérêt.